# How to do Python parallel API request processing?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm writing REST service on Python(Django), and this service should incorporate with another REST service by it's API.

Here some code and time of lines:

```
connection = statServer("myname", "mypassword")

q1 = connection.getJSONdict("query1") # approximately 15 seconds 
q2 = connection.getJSONdict("query2") # approximately 20 seconds
q3 = connection.getJSONdict("query3") # approximately 15 seconds

# my processing approximately 0.01 of second
# merge q1 + q2 + q3
```

It's clear to me that each request **getJSONdict("query")** actually do nothing apart from waiting on I/O, so it doesn't consume processor time.

Requests are sequentially, thus I could run them on separate threads. I know allegedly that Python don't provide real threading, but in my case I have waiting on I/O so I can to do something like threading.

I think this it is real often user case for Python, and if you have dealt with something like this task, please help to solve mine.

---

I have thoughts about Fork/Join framework or better will be ThreadExecutorPull to consume my requests (and for reusing threads) from all requests in my REST service.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to do it by myself.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool
# ... others imports

# You can dicede here to use processes or threads,
# if you want threads change Pool() to ThreadPool()
pool = Pool()
connection = statServer("myname", "mypassword")

res = pool.map(connection.getJSONdict, ["query1", "query2", "query3"])
print(res)
```